# How do I download and extract a list of papers in LaTeX format from arXiv?

Tags: python-requests, latex, pandoc

I have a list of papers that I'd like to extract from arXiv (I have the arxiv links / name of the arxvi file), but in the LaTeX format. How can I do this in Python?

If we go to this page: https://arxiv.org/format/2010.11645

We can read the following text:

> Source:
> Delivered as a gzipped tar (.tar.gz) file if there are multiple files, otherwise as a PDF file, or a gzipped TeX, DVI, PostScript or HTML (.gz, .dvi.gz, .ps.gz or .html.gz) file depending on submission format. [ Download source ]

We can download the file by clicking on [ Download source ], but I have no idea what type of file I'm getting back. The filename is simple `2010.11645`.

I'd like to download the file in LaTeX format (which I believe it .tex) and then convert it into .txt using `pandoc`. I believe I'd need to download the files via `requests` somehow?

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Rename the file to `2010.11645.tar.gz` and then use your favourite decompression tool to unzip it. No python needed.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that! I tried renaming to .tex and .txt, but wasn't getting what I wanted. How do I download files from a list of links, though?

Comment: you an iterate over your ids and download from https://arxiv.org/e-print/2010.11645

Comment: Ah! I was able to make it work with urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'filname.tar.gz')! Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you could also try *ar5iv.org*, a page that has almost all articles on arxiv as HTML5. Just replace the `x` in the url with a `5`.

Comment: @tarleb yeah, I tried it, but I think I'll be getting richer data with fewer artifacts if I use LaTeX with Pandoc.